# Домен для сайта с сервером Node.js

Tags: node.js

Есть сайт, сервер которого написан на node.js. Есть микрокомпьютер, который вычно включен. Хочу хранить сервер на нем. Но тут возникает вопрос: как задать доменное имя site.com для айпишника вида 1.234.567.890:1111 (на нем будет держаться сервер) и можно ли вообще так сделать?

Comment: сначала нужно купить выделенный IP у провайдера, затем подцепить DNS сервер и только после этого вы сможете подцепить купленное имя к компьютеру.

Comment: @Komdosh DNS необязателен, его могут предоставить регистраторы

Comment: 1. Динамический ДНС: https://dynv6.com/ 2. Порт поменять не получится. 3. Нужен белый ip (можно динамический, но белый).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно для начала купить домен и зарезервировать у вашего провайдера выделенный IP. На вашем сервере поднять службу DNS с выделенным IP. В панели управления доменом, где купили домен, привязать DNS, иначе называется ns-адреса. Как только привяжите, нужно дождаться глобального обновления DNS (обычно в районе 2-х часов), и тогда вы будете иметь доступ к серверу по домену.

Comment: DNS необязателен, его могут предоставить регистраторы

Comment: Согласен, посоветовал стабильный дедовский способ, проверенный временем, так сказать. Тем более, что нагрузки на сервер не создаст.